# Expand collapsed html tree table nodes

Tags: javascript, html, css, treenode

How to collapse all `tree nodes (except first node)` at run time and its first child node must be selected with some background color. We need only once node is opened rest of all collapsed. When we click of any collapsed node, expanded node must be collapsed and opened the clicked node with the same index of child node selection of previous opened. For example `Profitability(First Node)` node is opened with first child node selection, when we click on `(Growth) second or (Efficiency)` third parent node than first child node must be selected. Currently expand and collapse only happens with `plus(+) minus(-) buttons`. Is it possible to expand and collapse on parent node clicking? How we get parent node text with child node items on child node clicking? 
JSFIDDLE can be found here [Code sample](http://jsfiddle.net/AbuSufyan/Vd5BH/959/)  . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simple code will be appreciated .

Comment: Link, part of particular code (HTML, CSS, JS) would be great, this way we can only guess :D

Comment: Here is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AbuSufyan/Vd5BH/959/